# How to set Alt_L to Ctrl_L in xmodmap?

Tags: xmodmap

I can swap <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> with the following config

```
remove control = Control_L
remove mod1 = Alt_L
keycode 37 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 64 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
add control = Control_L
add mod1 = Alt_L
```

But, I have no ideas how to only set <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>. Basically, I don't want to change the original <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>, so in the end, there will be two <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> keys. How can I achieve that?

I tried to modify the above config, but no luck and always end up errors.

Thanks.

**Edited:**

People ask me to explain why I want this. I just want this to fit my habit.

The story in detail: I am using both macbook and normal laptop running Linux at the same time. The <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> position is just like the <kbd>Command</kbd> key in macbook. In macbook, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is copy, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is paste, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is closing tab etc..

<kbd>Command</kbd> in most cases in macbook is like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in non-macbook. I keep switching btw macbook and non-macbook laptop, this gives me headache. To make most of the shortcuts (position) be the same, the easiest way is to change <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>. I only care about the button position I am going to press instead of its actual meaning.

And the reason why I want to keep the <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> is the same reason. In terminal, I constantly using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to cut text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill a running process in foreground. I don't want to use the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> position for all of them after making <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> to be <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>. Thus, in the end, I want to have both <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> keys.

I normally don't need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combination at all. So it doesn't affect anything I work daily. If I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> in some cases, I can use the <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> instead. Or even make <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> to be <kbd>Alt_L</kbd>. That is another non-important part. The most important part is to make <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> to be <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> and keep <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> to be <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>.

I think people may say I shouldn't do this. But, This is really what I want and make life easier. Otherwise, I keep pressing the wrong keys and end up messing many things.

Thanks a lot.

PS: one more thing, why don't change macbook shortcuts or keys? Apple makes things very strict. Changes in Linux are always easier and doable. :)

Comment: Please edit question and explain **why** you want to "set Alt_L to Ctrl_L". Is there an application that reads keysyms, and you'll have to pretend to it that your Alt_L key is Ctrl_L? Is there an application that uses X modifier bits, and you want to use both Alt_L and Ctrl_L for this modifier? Something else?

Comment: @dirkt thank you very much for your reply. I have updated the question with detail explanation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like (untested)

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
add control = Alt_L
```

and see in which applications it works.

X keyboard event have a number of "modifiers", and "control is pressed" is one of them. With the above `xmodmap` commands, the <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> now doesn't set the bit for `mod1` (which is Alt), but for `control`.

This will only work for applications that check the modifiers; it won't work for applications that explictiely check for <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can also try to make the <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> key produce the symbol for <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>:

```
keycode 64 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
```

So try both and see which works better for your use case.

Don't forget to reset or undo the layout changes before you try a different change. (Figuring out the commands how to undo above changes is a nice exercise).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I tried to execute the three lines in order. So far so good. I haven't seen any problems yet. One last problem is I can not load those rules after login automatically. I am wondering if you know any solution on this? I checked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257043/starting-xmodmap-on-login-12-10) which is actually not solved until now. I am running xfce. Thanks a lot. (btw, I have upvoted and marked your answer as the answer.)